# Efficenty of Video Processing on Raspberry Pi and OpenCV

Tags: python, optimization, process, raspberry-pi3, opencv3.1

The goal is a small video analysis program with the **Raspberry Pi 3 B** with camera and a TV for gymnastics. So the program will capture the input of the camera, buffer it a set length (let's say 5 seconds) and give it then out to the screen. Now in this video stream it should be possible to navigate around like you are watching a normal video with the following functions. Pause and Play. Rewind, change speed, frame by frame, jump back or forward set amount of frames.

Now I tried to realize this with Python and OpenCV. The problem I encounter is the following:

If I capture the camera output and write it to a file with OpenCV I get a CPU load of 50-70%, with displaying the delayed view and navigation in it. I seem to be to inefficient as I get a frame rate of 10 fps with a resolution of 720x400px, higher you can forget performance wise and less is to bad quality. I would like to point out that I was using threads to try to improve the fps. Reading camera, and reading file are running both over separated threads.

Now I figured that the writing to a file goes much faster with using raspivid as it uses the hardware encoder for h264 and ends up using 0-1% of the CPU for that. Unfortunately OpenCV (3.1.0) seems to have a problem with the output file that I generate. I'm creating a .h264 file that I then open with my python script with OpenCV. But it seems like that the OpenCV can't read the keyframes because when I try to change the next frame to read with

`cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,jumpToFrame)`

and read it then again it always jumps to frame 0. Same when I try to set the milliseconds.

Here is a list of different raspivid configurations I tried

```
raspivid -v -w 720 -h 400 -n -t 0 -fps 20 -o data.h264

raspivid -g 1 -v -w 720 -h 400 -n -t 100 -fps 20 -o data.h264

raspivid -g 1 -ih -qp 10 -v -pf main -w 720 -h 400 -n -t 100 -fps 20 -o data.h264
```

So I tried to change the output of the keyframes of raspivid with the -g 1 parameter but that doesn't seem to fix the problem either. Also played with some other settings, but did't get anywhere.

So now to some of my questions. Do you think this project is possible to realize with the Raspberry Pi, with a resolution not less then 720x400px and a frame rate of at least 20fps or better 30fps?

If yes, do you think writing the buffer of the videoStream into a file for in between saving is a good idea? Or should I consider keeping it in variable? Maybe a list? But it looks like a bad idea as it seems like one raw frame in opencv has the size of 7.1MB (I tried writing the numpy arrays with pytables in a file as well).

For me the closest to working I got with the above described problem that I can't solve.

I also considered if somehow streaming the output can be an option through VLC or GStreamer for example. But I'm not if can manage to fix the keyframe problem.

When I write the file with opencv and codec "MJPG" and the file extension .avi then the keyframe handling works fine in OpenCV, but it's to intense of a process to have both running at the same time as I only get 8fps (while using threads, or is it maybe because I use threads).

Now I'm not expecting you to solve all my problems, I'm more wondering about your opinion what attempt you think seems the most promising.